# Excel formula for counting combinations of checked boxes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help with a formula that counts unique combination of events from a checkbox form. Users check how many times they completed a task X, Y or Z. The program counts how many events were logged (under '#') and then the counts the unique combination of events and spits out the combo count (under 'Combinations').

[image: Checkbox Form]

For the sake of clarification, I'll refer to each category by its name and each numbered checkbox as X_1, X_2, etc.

Here are the design criteria:

1. Count unique combinations between two separate events (e.g. [X_1,Y_1])
2. Once a single instance of an event is counted, you cannot use it again (e.g. X_1 cannot be paired up twice => [X_1,Y_1], [X_1,Y_2])
3. However, you can pair multiple instances of the same event to other unique events (e.g. [X_1,Y_1], [X_2,Y_2], [X_3,Z_1])
4. Combinations cannot be made between multiple instances of the same event (i.e. [X_1,X_2] is not valid)

So in the example above, the correct number of combinations should be 3 (i.e. three unique combos of events with each individual event counted only once). I've built two formulas. The first (H2) uses INT and COUNTIF functions to count number of checked boxes column-by-column. It yields an incorrect answer of two.

`=INT(COUNTIF(C2:C4,true)/2)+INT(COUNTIF(D2:D4,true)/2)+INT(COUNTIF(E2:E4,true)/2)+INT(COUNTIF(F2:F4,true)/2)+INT(COUNTIF(G2:G4,true)/2)`

The second (H3) uses the INT and SUM function to estimate a total from the data container in column A. It yields an incorrect answer of 4.

```
=INT(SUM($A$2:$A$18)/2)
```

I believe the MOD function may work well in addition to the COUNTIF function. Go column-by-column, count unique combinations, and any remainder will count towards finding an odd event in the next column.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Please don't post your formulas as a screenshot.  And it would better to also post your data as text.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125018/186471

Comment: Formulas have been posted to the original post. The desired result is an output of '3' under combinations. And here's the google doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1miKCBZmQPc5aTH019U49YoBLGQXdaRgehfW0m2JW7i0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome MF!  I'm afraid I still uncertain what we are trying to count up.  Number 3 in your design criteria says "you can pair multiple instances of the same event to other unique events (e.g. XY, XY, XZ)".  Is that meant to be XY, XZ, YZ?  to give the three unique pairings?  And to confirm, you can't count both XY and YX - they are the same thing?  And #2 says "Once a single instance of an event is counted, you cannot use it again".  Do you mean "Once a single instance of an event PAIRING (eg. XY, same as YX) is counted, you cannot use it again"?

Comment: And lastly, how are the checkboxes useful? Do you mean that five checked checkboxes should be recognised as meaning "Event X"?  So instead of thinking of them as events, they could be considered sequences or patterns of checkboxes?  Or am I way off here...?  If my questions make sense, please edit your question to add the clarifications up there.

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work, in H5?  I think it gives the correct number of possible pairings.

```
=MIN((MAX(1,C10)+MAX(1,D10)+MAX(1,E10)+MAX(1,F10)+MAX(1,G10) - COUNT(C10:G10)),
      INT(COUNTIF(C2:G9,TRUE)/2))
```

It uses a helper row, which totals the number of different users for each possible attempt, in cells C10:G10.  This only needs to be entered once.
The formula in H10 is:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C9,true)
```

and it needs to be dragged across under all of the checkboxes, ie in H10 to G10.

Here is my result.

[image]

It would be possible to eliminate the helper row, doing the totals below the checkboxes, but it would make the formula very messy I think.